# Chromium and Firefox display colors differently and I don't know which one is doing it right

Tags: browser, colors, chromium, color-profile

I've been building a website under Ubuntu 17.10 and use Firefox and Chromium for testing. The two browsers show quite different colors (not only for images but all colors) and I always thought that it is Chromium which for some reason wrongly over-saturates them, so up until now I always chose colors that looked right in Firefox.

But I'm starting to get more and more complaints about the website's background being too purple - which it shouldn't be in my opinion as only the blue component of it's color (#eeeeff) is "elevated", but it has reached a point that more people are seeing it as purple than blue, what makes me confused.

This is the aforementioned color displayed in Firefox (left) and Chromium (right).

[image: color #eeeeff as displayed in FF and Chromium]

And this is how I see a website:

[image]

The difference is quite large (notice how even the favicon is different) and I'm asking you to tell me which one is the browser I should trust when choosing the colours of my websites and whether I could do something to avoid it being displayed so differently in different browsers.

(There are some users that see the overly saturated colors in Firefox too. So now which is the right one, really?)

Comment: This happens to me in second monitors

Comment: This Seems like a common concerns. So my question is, in development, do we choose colors that look best on Chrome with this default color profile that's incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option is to open `chrome://flags/` and select the option **sRGB** on the **Force color profile** item.

[image: Force color profile setting on Chrome flags]

By using this setting instead of disabling the *Use hardware acceleration when available*, you don't lose some nice features like the 3D view on Google Maps.

Solution found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/74h5yh/blue_shows_as_purple_in_chrome/

Comment: Not really an answer. You cannot(as far as I know) force user's browser to use sRGB, you can only change it for yourself. If you are trying to get consistency of your website for all of your users i think we are all out of luck. Let me know what you think about this. I actually asked similar question and nobody has any answer for this problem

Comment: Not sure if there's a browser bug, so I filed two issues: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1133990 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1668444

Comment: This works on Brave too. I was automatically redirected to `brave://flags/`

Answer (score 3):

Using GPick as a Color Picker and calling a Website with Color Hexcode like

http://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/54430

I see, that Firefox renders the RGB Colors exactly, meaning GPick identifies the same Hex Code from CSS.
Whereas Chromium renders some kind of differnt color.

You can call

[chrome://flags/#force-color-profile](http://chrome://flags/#force-color-profile)

and set the Color Profile in Chromium to sRGB, so the rendered Color from Chromium is identified the same as the HexCode with GPick.

Comment: Not really an answer. You cannot(as far as I know) force user's browser to use sRGB, you can only change it for yourself. If you are trying to get consistency of your website for all of your users i think we are all out of luck. Let me know what you think about this. I actually asked similar question and nobody has any answer for this problem

Comment: @JonNezbit The question was not: How to render the Webpage for all browsers consistently, but: "Which browser is doing it right?"

Using RGB ColorPicker is one option to answer this question.

Comment: I was refering to "...whether I could do something to avoid it being displayed so differently in different browsers...". Which exactly what I am wondering and searching for literary every day

Comment: @JonNezbit When Chrome doesnt render the colours in the same way firefox does, and this is the same for images, you can do two things, imho:

1.)Build a browser switch like in the old times and deliver different content for chorme users
2.) Persuade Chrome to switch their behaviour

Comment: Thats clever. I will think about delivering different content to chrome users. Upwoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable 'Use hardware acceleration when available' in Chromium Settings and relaunch, Chromium displays colors correctly. When turned on, Chromium colors are off. I consider this as a workaround until Chromium color management issue with hardware acceleration is resolved.

Comment: Not really an answer. You cannot(as far as I know) force user's browser to use your settings (hardware acceleration), you can only change it for yourself. If you are trying to get consistency of your website for all of your users i think we are all out of luck. Let me know what you think about this. I actually asked similar question and nobody has any answer for this problem

Answer (score 0):

With the other two colours being equal, your colour is right in the middle of "blue territory".

If you convert it to HSL and look on the hue line, you can see it is right in the middle of the "blue" frequency range.

[image]

Consequently, any hint of green or red is incorrect.