# why is grey displayed differently on different browsers?

Tags: html, css

Hi im  new to web development but  i've noticed a problem with the colorization of my site; when i set the css background color to gray, the same site displays differently. Firefox displays the site in a shade lighter than chromium.

I've tried searching online and on this site, but all the results that i've seen were irrelevant (they talk about fonts being displayed differently)

please visit my github.io site (https://kingsslave.github.io) to see the problem live, but if you dont want to, here is the css I used:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    background-color:gray;
    width:100%;
}
```

if you want, I can post everything here. I also took a screenshot that shows the problem: https://kingsslave.github.io/images/screenshot.png

I want to make the color the same on all browsers. Any help you can provide would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using keywords like 'gray', consider using color hex values to set you color.

Comment: @Wimanicesir AFAIK `gray` is `gray`. AKA: `#808080` **everywhere**.

Comment: Adding to @Wimanicesir , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054534/6024572) seems relevant.

Comment: Also, read 2nd paragraph at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names) section of wikipedia article on Web colors.

Comment: The color name should be fine, could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129374/723769

Comment: @Wimanicesir i just tried #aaa but the colors are still being displayed differently

Comment: I'd say _everything_ looks darker in Chromium, not just the color `grey`. Compare other areas. Also your screenshot doesn't seem consistent with the site. The screenshot seems brigher. `grey`s on it are `111` (chromium) and `170` (firefox); not `128`.

Comment: Also people can't guess your exact problem. They should be able to reproduce it, and to do that, they need to know all the variables, e.g. OS, browser (+version), monitor (calibration?), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many theories for this as Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox. you can check more about that here

1. [Colours are different in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox)
2. [Color Rendering Difference: Firefox vs. Safari](https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/)
3. [Web browser color management guide](https://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/)
4. [How Your Web Browser Affects the Way Colors Are Rendered](https://fstoppers.com/education/how-your-web-browser-affects-way-colors-are-rendered-77241)
5. [Chrome NEEDS to support Colour Management like it's competitors.](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0lO7YRdLD5ok/?hl=en&gpf=d/category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/lO7YRdLD5ok)

Hope this will help you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try using `#808080` instead of `grey`.

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: i tried #aaa but the colors are still being displayed differently. See comment above.