# Fix browser color differences from developer side

Tags: css

These are two images that show the same blue color: `#6666FF`, in Chrome it shows as purple, in Firefox it shows as blue:

[image]

I can fix it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129374/chromium-and-firefox-display-colors-differently-and-i-dont-know-which-one-is-do) (also described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/74h5yh/blue_shows_as_purple_in_chrome/)) by changing my Chrome color profile settings. **Is there way to fix it through css**, because I don't want my users to see my website with totally different colors?

Comment: You can't change how a browser handles colors, I don't see anything wrong with slightly different colors between browsers, Browsers have always had these quirky behaviors, as long as it doesn't hurt your app or UX it's nothing to be concerned with.

Comment: you can fix it through css for a specific browser like if you want to change it for google chrome it will get changed for it but not for safari since the color will be differently shown there so you need to do it from the setting I hope that I am correct...

Comment: It might also be an issue with the image file itself, if it has any specific color profile information embedded - some browsers try and make use of that. The solution to get it displayed the same across browsers would then be to remove that information from the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll never have your users, at least most of them, see the exact colors you want them to see.

What you're seeing between the two browsers on your monitor also happens between monitors. Monitor brand A will display differently than monitor brand B. Heck, this even happens when the monitors are the SAME brand, the SAME model, and the SAME settings. For example, I have a three monitor setup, each monitor is the same brand and model number. Yet, one of the three is quite different even when all three have the same settings. I've adjusted the third one as much as possible to match the other two, but it's still a bit off. The other two are very very close, but, if you pay attention, there is a perceptible difference.

The demand of consistent color also ignores that users might adjust their monitors to be warmer, cooler, saturated, unsaturated, etc., etc. which would affect their perception of your color choices.

Just work from a basis where you're monitor settings are not skewed to much one way or another and know that's about the best you can do.